# aapt missing but its there

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-studio

I had to reinstall ubuntu-14.04-64 due to reasons.

After this reinstall, when I try to build my android projets, I get a bunch of these lines (among others) in output:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/gps/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Now, I know this file exists in my setup because this:

```
gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~$ ls -l /home/gps/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gps gps 1146608 Jan  4 18:47 /home/gps/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt
gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~$ file  /home/gps/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt
/home/gps/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=fc8aded5418584519d59f2133e81184fe3d4bdfd, not stripped
gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~$
```

I have installed all sdk tools from v19 onwards. Changing project settings to any of them shows same error.

Also, trying to execute the file directly gives same error:

```
gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~$ /home/gps/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt
bash: /home/gps/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: No such file or directory
```

Can someone suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: You have a 64-bit OS, but your binaries are for a 32-bit architecture. Did you use a 32-bit OS before? Are 64-bit versions available? In theory it should be possible to run them if you have the 32-bit versions of all needed libraries installed.

Comment: Actually, I had same ubuntu 64bit installed previously. I backed up sdk directory before install.
I reinstalled fresh sdk, which gave this problem. Then i replaces SDK with backup copy, which still gave this problem.

Comment: Either way is there a way to install 32 bit libs?  apt-get install ia32-libs doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably missing some dynamic link library that the program needs. Run this command to list the libraries it uses and install those that are missing:

```
ldd /home/gps/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt
```

Comment: Tried this. Get following output:

"not a dynamic executable"

Comment: The very least you'll need libc6: `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386` Try again after that

Comment: Needed sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev:i386 also. Thanks.
I'll format it all into an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved as follows:

Issue was missing 32 bit libraries, libc and zlib in this case. Installed using following :

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev:i386
```

Thanks @Joni for clear directions.

Comment: How did you figure that you are missing these exact libraries: **libc6:i386** and **zlib1g-dev:i386**?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember exact answer for you now, must've been something in logs.

Answer (score 3):

Solution as of Ubuntu 16.04 / 16.10 to enable 32 bit binaries to run on 64 bit host

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get -qqy update
sudo apt-get -qqy install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```