# What is difference between 32-bit gcc and 64-bit gcc with -m32 option?

Tags: c, macos, ubuntu, cross-compiling, cpu-architecture

My team have been working on JNI recently so we faced different issues regarding 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. Let's take an example (`temp.c`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
  printf("long=%d\n",sizeof(long));
}
```

**Is there any difference between `gcc_32_bit temp.c` and `gcc_64_bit -m32 temp.c`?**

**Cases tested:**

**Case-1:** code compiled on 64-bit ubuntu using `gcc temp.c`. **Output:** `long=8` on 64-bit ubuntu.

**Case-2:** code compiled on 64-bit ubuntu using `gcc -m32 temp.c`. **Output:** `long=4` on 64-bit ubuntu.

**Case-3:** code compiled on 64-bit MAC ([64-bit cross compiler used](http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=compiling_for_linux)) using `/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux64/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gcc temp.c`. **Output:** `long=8` on 64-bit ubuntu.

**Case-4:** code compiled on 64-bit MAC ([32-bit cross compiler used](http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=compiling_for_linux)) using `/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32/bin/i586-pc-linux-gcc temp.c`. **Output:** `Error: cannot run` on 64-bit ubuntu.

We are using MAC cross compiler because we do not have 32-bit linux machine.

Comment: Could you not run a 32-bit Linux instance in a VM?

Comment: Maybe it helps to check the target environment of the executable with 'file <exe>'.

Comment: @GoBusto it will take some time to setup actually. So we managed to get a 32-bit cross compiler over MAC.

Comment: What is the *exact error message* you get when you try to run the cross-compiled binary? There should be no difference between the output of a 64-bit compiler building a 32-bit binary and a 32-bit compiler building a 32-bit binary. An interesting exercise would be doing a diff on a disassembly of the two different binaries, and including this info in your question.

Comment: You should likely be including the architecture in your compilation command (eg. `-arch i386 -arch x86_64`). Also, selecting `-m32` does not necessarily restrict the compiler to using only instructions which are available on the `i386`. Selecting `-march=i386` does restrict the compiler, and the default `-march` option is determined by how the compiler was configured when it was built.

Comment: The ubuntu installation is probably missing a dynamically linked library needed by the 32-bit program cross-compiled on the Mac.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620094/aapt-missing-but-its-there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could seem a little weird, but it has started working out of nowhere.

As [amdn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521897/amdn) posted in comments above, it could be due to some missing library for 32-bit. Since it was not working earlier, I installed gcc-multilib and some auto updates of Ubuntu and it has started working.

Thank you everyone for your great help.